# Adding a class to an element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to add a class to a certain element with another class.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li class="hide">Item 4</li>
  <li class="hide">Item 5</li>
<ul>
```

JS/Jquery

```js
if($('li').hasClass('hide')) {
  $('li').removeClass('hide').addClass('slide-down');
}
```

The problem is that the class `slide-down` gets added to all `li` elements.

Is there a way to only target the `li` elements that have the `hide` class removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mh maybe it's due to the typo in your HTML: `class"hide"` (you are missing the equal sign).

Also you got a logical error in your code:

1. `if($('li').hasClass('hide'))` the condition will yield true if any `<li>` element in your document has the `hide` class.
2. `$('li').removeClass('hide').addClass('slide-down');` the first segment `$('li')` will actually select ALL `<li>` elements in your document and remove the class `hide` from them and add the `slide-down` to ALL `<li>` elements in your document.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$('li.hide').removeClass('hide').addClass('slide-down');
```

Note that jQuery is about chaining, i.e selecting subsets and applying functions to these subsets.

What this line does is:

1. `$('li.hide')` selects all `<li>` elements in your document which have the `hide` class - this becomse your "working subset" now.
2. `.removeClass('hide')` removes the `hide` class from this subset we got in the first step and returns the same subset again.
3. `.addClass('slide-down')` adds the `slide-down` class to all `<li>` in the selected subset returned from step 2, which is the same as from step 1.

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0nzaa7t/

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS:

```
var liHide = document.querySelectorAll('li.hide');
var i;
var length = liHide.length;

for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
    liHide[i].className = 'slide-down';
}
```

Note that, for some reason, `querySelectorAll` doesn't get updated automatically like `document.getElementsByClassName`. The same code wouldn't work if we would have used that method for querying the DOM:

```
var liHide = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
var i;
var length = liHide.length;

for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
    liHide[i].className = 'slide-down'; //<-- this won't update the 2nd element
}
```

This would have only changed the first element, since `liHide[1]` becomes `liHide[0]`, because `<li class="hide">Item 4</li>` is no longer part of HTML Collection.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which behaves like a "live" array, whereas `document.querySelectorAll` returns a non-"live" `NodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

Plain javascript for the ones with `querySelectorAll` and `classList` support:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('li.hide');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('hide');
    items[i].classList.add('slide-down');
}
```

Without `querySelectorAll`:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].classList.contains('hide')) {
        items[i].classList.remove('hide');
        items[i].classList.add('slide-down');
    }
}
```

Without `querySelectorAll` and `classList`:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (new RegExp(/(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g).test(items[i].className)) {
        items[i].className = items[i].className.replace(/(?:^|\s)hide(?!\S)/g , '');
        items[i].className += ' ' + 'slide-down';
    }
}
```